# Importing Cordova 6.1.2-Project to Eclipse: cordovalib.jar missing in Android Dependencies

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I create a cordova project and build it like this:

```
cordova create /my_folder/FlugbuchFPG com.MyName.FlugbuchFPG FlugbuchFPG

cd /my_folder/FlugbuchFPG

cordova platform add android --save

Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
    Path: platforms/android
    Package: com.MyName.FlugbuchFPG
    Name: FlugbuchFPG
    Activity: MainActivity
    Android target: android-25
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Android project created with cordova-android@6.1.2
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist@1" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for android

               This plugin is only applicable for versions of cordova-android greater than 4.0. If you have a previous platform version, you do *not* need this plugin since the whitelist will be built in.

Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-whitelist" to config.xml
--save flag or autosave detected
Saving android@~6.1.2 into config.xml file ...

Installed platforms:
  android 6.1.2
Available platforms: 
  amazon-fireos ~3.6.3 (deprecated)
  blackberry10 ~3.8.0
  browser ~4.1.0
  firefoxos ~3.6.3
  ios ~4.3.0
  osx ~4.0.1
  webos ~3.7.0

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-17,android-18,android-19,android-20,android-21,android-22,android-23,android-N,android-25,Google Inc.:Google APIs:17,Google Inc.:Google APIs:18,Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19,Google Inc.:Google APIs (x86 System Image):19,Google Inc.:Google APIs:19,Google Inc.:Google APIs:21,Google Inc.:Google APIs:22,Google Inc.:Google APIs:23
Gradle: installed 

cordova build

ANDROID_HOME=/Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Starting a new Gradle Daemon for this build (subsequent builds will be faster).
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders
:CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources
:CordovaLib:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl
:compileDebugRenderscript
:generateDebugBuildConfig
:generateDebugResValues
:generateDebugResources
:mergeDebugResources
:processDebugManifest
:processDebugResources
:generateDebugSources
:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugSources
:mergeDebugShaders
:compileDebugShaders
:generateDebugAssets
:mergeDebugAssets
:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
:validateSigningDebug
:packageDebug
:assembleDebug
:cdvBuildDebug

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 19.753 secs
Built the following apk(s): 
    /my_folder/FlugbuchFPG/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
```

I download the android-debug.apk to my Android-Device and it works fine.

Then I try to import the project to Eclipse 4.4.2. I choose -> File -> Import... -> Android -> Existing Android Code into Workspace

Eclipse offers me 6 packages. I choose only the "MainActivity" and "CordovaLib", as all the others have the word "debug" either in the path or in the name. I rename "MainAvtivity" to name of my app and "CordovaLib" to "ProjectnameCordovaLib".

The import runs but the project is marked red due to errors. When I go to "right-click -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Android Dependencies" it tells me that the cordovalib.jar is missing in the bin-Folder. Indeed the bin-Folder is completely empty.

When I remove the entry from the Android Dependencies, other errors accure. So that seems not to be the solution. So how can I create oder get the missing cordovalib.jar or fix this issue in a different way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else has this problem:

Finnaly I deleted all cordova projects from my harddrive, uninstalled eclipse, downloded the new version of eclipse and - important! - chose a different directory as workspace than before. It seems just uninstalling and reinstalling eclipse does not help if you use the same workspace because eclipse somehow remembers the old workspace and the error occured again. After choosing a new workspace-dorectory I re-generated the cordova projects and imported them to eclispe and now the error was gone and I could build the app.